# I have two Data frames. I want to replace the values of one dataframe with the header values of another dataframe based on a condition

Tags: python, pandas

One of my data frames (df1) looks like:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5

A       B       C       D       E
B       X       Y       null    null
C       E       null    null    null
```

Another data frame(df2) looks like:

```
Val1    Val2    Val3

A       D       X
C       Y       null
B       null    null
E       null    null
```

The final data frame(final) I want is:

```
Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4    Col5

Val1    Val1    Val1    Val2    Val1
Val1    Val3    Val2    null    null
Val1    Val1    null    null    null
```

*If you want to know why I have this weird condition to satisfy: I am trying to do feature engineering here. I have grouped the similar features from df1 manually in df2.

Say, "Python", "Java", "C", these 3 go under the the column "Programming"*
"Leadership", "Communication", "Presentation", goes under "Soft Skills"

Comment: What's the logic here to replace values from df1 by df2?

Comment: @AkshayNevrekar - I edited my post and explained it on why I need it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use [`melt`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) with remove missing values by [`dropna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dropna.html) and then [`replace`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.replace.html) by `dictionary`:

```
df = df2.melt().dropna()
d = dict(zip(df['value'],df['variable']))
#alternative
#d = df.set_index('value')['variable']
print (d)
{'A': 'Val1', 'C': 'Val1', 'B': 'Val1', 'E': 'Val1', 'D': 'Val2', 'Y': 'Val2', 'X': 'Val3'}

df1 = df1.replace(d)
#alternative
#df1 = df1.apply(lambda x: x.map(d)).fillna(df1)
print (df1)
   Col1  Col2  Col3  Col4  Col5
0  Val1  Val1  Val1  Val2  Val1
1  Val1  Val3  Val2   NaN   NaN
2  Val1  Val1   NaN   NaN   NaN
```